Is there a way to delete folders through GitLab from master branch, but keep them in other branches?
I'm sure this is a stupid question but I have very little background with git and everything I've learned has been done on the fly and independently, so I'm very much still learning.
I have a directory with two branches at the moment: master and side-branch. They are currently identical, but I have a bunch of files and folders I would like to remove from master and leave only in side-branch.
I tried git rm -r ../myfolder which fails because it's a folder, not a file. I saw one suggestion to use git rm -r --cached ../myfolder, which does remove it from tracking but I would like to also delete it in my directory on that branch. Manually deleting after that just removes it from everywhere.

It's possible, but why do you want to do this?

@JimRedmond Basically, the master branch is a bunch of _index.md files built into a website (via hugo). Previously, I was keeping .md files that weren't ready as 'drafts' and updating them when they were complete, but now we have a lot more users that will be adding things. So I made a new branch that I could keep the drafts/unfinished files on (and others will have their own branches eventually), but I would like to remove them from master so master is a clean copy of just the necessary and complete files for the site.

What will you do when somebody merges the two branches (intentionally or otherwise)?

Your title asks to do it in GitLab, but in your body you shoul Git commands. Which one is it? But creating a new commit with files removed will not affect any other commits (and subsequently other branches), because commits are immutable. Once created, they can never be changed again.

@knittl yeah that was unclear, sorry--I am trying to do it through git commands, though I'm completely open to a better way.
So you're saying if I remove files from a side branch, commit them on that branch, and checkout master again they should still be there? And if so, is the command in my body for removing wrong somehow?

@JimRedmond that's kind of the plan, to let people work on their branches and then use merge requests to incorporate their additions. For the actual merging probably git-mergetool.

No, the command is not wrong, but it needs to -f flag to remove the files from your working tree too. Any uncommitted changes will be lost.
